# Chromium youtube videos show black screen, only audio no visual content of videos

Tags: 16.04, video, flash, chromium

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. After I run the following commands, chromium starts, I can surf without any problem, but it is not showing video content anymore, only audio.

```
sudo apt-get install update
sudo apt-get install upgrade
```

It shows only black screen, audio works super fine but however no visual. I think it has something to do with flash or other plugins, but I am not sure. 
I've enabled `always run frome chromium:plugins` but nothing has changed. I've installed flash plugin and enable canonical partners updates, still doesn't work. Meanwhile firefox works well.

Please help me.

I still don't know what is the problem but in one of facebook groups someone helped me to solve the problem:

- paste this on the address bar `> chrome://flags`
- click enable on Override software rendering list Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what is the problem but in one of facebook groups someone helped me to solve the problem

paste this on the address bar> chrome://flags

click enable on Override software rendering list Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android